# Iterate over array of objects and concatenate their attributes which are arrays themselves

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, concatenation

I have an array of objects that have an array as attribute. I want to concatenate these attributes. I'm doing this:

```
result = []
objects.each { |obj| result.concat(obj.attr) }
```

which works but looks bad. I tried

```
objects.reduce(:attr)
```

which does not work. It's a Rails app, and I want to concatenate related items into a single array. I want this:

```
[{
  attr: [1,2]
},{
  attr: [3,4]
}]
```

to turn into this:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Array#map` :-

```
result = objects.map { |obj| obj.attr }
```

If you want the `result` array to be flattened :-

```
result = objects.flat_map { |obj| obj.attr }
```

Comment: This does not work for me in Rails... It returns#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Location:0x0000000502a990>. I'm new to Ruby and Rails, and don't know how to properly work with this Rails relational objects...

Comment: @BrazhnykYuriy You said `objects.each { |obj| result.concat(obj.attr) }` worked, so my one also should work...

Comment: Ah...it works but for your example to work i MUST flatten... But how do i provide only one level of recursiveness? So it will get rid of collection of collectins but does not flatten all other arrays

Comment: @BrazhnykYuriy yes.. `objects.map { |obj| obj.attr }.flatten(1)`

Comment: I have ended up doing it like this: ".map(&:attr).flatten(1)"